# Get id/name in request.POST Django

Tags: html, django, httprequest, wagtail

i'am trying to get the id of the clicked li element but i don't get it 
i need some help here ,and thanks in advance

**Edit**:i'am using wagtail cms and my app is based on 
models.py:

```
class index(Page)
    def get_context(self, request):
     base_tags = ["foo","boo","voo"]
        if request.method == "POST" :
            tag = request.POST[("id","")]
            blogpages = BlogPage.objects.live().filter(tags__name__in=[tag])
        return #....
```

index.html:

```
<form id="content" method="post">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {%for tag in base_tags %}
  <li   name="id" value="{{tag.id}}" onclick="content.submit();"  role="presentation"><a href="#{{tag}}" aria-controls="{{tag}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{tag}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: This really isn't how forms work. But why do you want to use a form at all? Why not a standard link, whose URL contains the tag value?

Comment: do you have a better idea ? i tried a lot but no one worked

Comment: i need a post method to get the tag and filter the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a form here at all. Use a standard link:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  {% for tag in base_tags %}
     <li aria-controls="{{tag}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><a href="{% url "tags" tag %}">{{tag}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and define your URL and view like this:

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>/w+)/$', tag_view, 'tags'),
```

...

```
def tag_view(request, tag):
    blogpages = BlogPage.objects.live().filter(tags__name=tag)
```

Comment: i forgot to note that i'am using wagtail cms and my app is based on models, i  will edit the post

Comment: can i use slugurl directly without defining the url